# How to get two value just using one serializerMethodField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When 'content' field is excluded, I want to add "NOT content contained" at 'sth' field, else "content contatined"

serializers.py

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sth = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'sth', 'content', 'created',)

    def get_sth(self, obj):
        return
```

Response what I want to get

```
[
    {
      "id": "1",
      "sth": "content contained",
      "content": "a",
      "created": "2020-01-23"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "sth": "NOT content contained",
      "created": "2020-01-22"
    },
]
```

How can I get the reponse like above.

Comment: how did you * exclude* the `content` field *only for some items*?

Comment: I did using .values() function.

Answer (score 2):

Modify it in your `to_representation` method like this

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'content', 'created',)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        if content is not included:
           data.update({'sth': "content contained"})
        else:
           data.update({'sth': "NOT content contained"})
        return data
```

You have to set `content is not included` condition according to your system.

Answer (score 0):

> drf has one of the feature named as ** .to_representation**
>   https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#baseserializer

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sth = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'sth', 'content', 'created',)

    def get_sth(self, obj):
        return 

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ** here you can modify the your data what you want to represent **
        return [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "sth": "content contained",
                "content": "a",
                "created": "2020-01-23"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "sth": "NOT content contained",
                "created": "2020-01-22"
            },
       ]
```

Answer (score 0):

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sth = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

```
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('id', 'sth', 'content', 'created',)

def get_sth(self, obj):
    return 

def valdiate_content(self,value):
    if self.sth == 'content contained':
         return self.value
def to_internal_value(self,data):
    if self.sth === 'NOT content contained':
         data.pop('content')
    return super(PostSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
```

Something like this might work